# How to call methods in the main so that they output on the same line?

Tags: java

I am trying to construct an image and I want all of the methods to come out on the same line but so far this is what I'm getting. I can't figure out how to get the next method called to appear on the same line/right next to the previous method. Can anyone help?

```
public class Diamonds {    
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
    //calling the methods to put the logo together
    triangleB(); //part of top diamond
    triangleA(); //part of top diamond
    triangleC(); //part of top diamond
    triangleD(); //part of top diamond
    triangleB(); //part of bottom left diamond
    drawBox(); //part of bottom left diamond
    triangleD(); //part of bottom left diamond
    triangleC(); //part of bottom right diamond
    drawBox(); //part of bottom right diamond
    triangleA(); //part of bottom right diamond

}

public static void triangleA () throws IOException {
    //creates top right piece of top diamond and piece of bottom right diamond
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("config.txt"));

    int size = fileInput.nextInt();
    int y = fileInput.nextInt();

    while (y <= size) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= size; x++) {
            if ( x <= y) System.out.print("*");
            else System.out.print(" ");}
        y++;
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void triangleB () throws IOException {
    //creates top left piece of top diamond and piece of bottom left diamond
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("config.txt"));

    int size = fileInput.nextInt();
    int y = fileInput.nextInt();

    while (y <= size) {
        for (int x = size; x >= 0; x--) {
            if ( x <= y) System.out.print("*");
            else System.out.print(" ");}
        y++;
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void triangleC () throws IOException {
    //creates bottom left piece of top diamond and piece of bottom right diamond
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("config.txt"));

    int size = fileInput.nextInt();
    int y = fileInput.nextInt();

    while (y <= size) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= size; x++) {
            if ( x >= y) System.out.print("*");
            else System.out.print(" ");}
        y++;
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void triangleD () throws IOException {
    //creates bottom right piece of top diamond and piece of bottom left diamond
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("config.txt"));

    int size = fileInput.nextInt();
    int y = fileInput.nextInt();

    while (y <= size) {
        for (int x = size; x >= 0; x--) {
            if ( x >= y) System.out.print("*");
            else System.out.print(" ");}
        y++;
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void drawLine () throws IOException {
    //method used to draw lines for the box
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("config.txt"));

    int size = fileInput.nextInt();

    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        System.out.print("**"); //two asterisks instead of one to create a box with longer length than height
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void drawBox () throws IOException {
    //method to draw a box for the bottom diamonds
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("config.txt"));

    int size = fileInput.nextInt();
    int y = fileInput.nextInt();

    while (y <= size) {
        drawLine();
        y++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`.

Comment: Please post your code in your question. It is unreadable in a comment.

Comment: By the way, the goal here is to output the Mitsubishi logo.

Comment: There's not going to be a simple way to do this.  You will have to combine these methods together so they all interleave, e.g. you print the first line from _all_ the functions at once, then the second line from all the functions at once, etc.  There's not going to be a way around that.

Comment: I am just in a beginning programming class, literally the first of the sequence and we are supposed to be using nested loops and separate methods to do this. Seems like there should be a pretty simple solution to this that I can't seem to get.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use printf() instead of println()